geometry nodes advect points using vdb or embergen particle velocity
I've run into a problem when trying create curves that follow a simulation from embergen. I've tried a few routes but they all seem to be dead ends
Option 1
trace then create curves from points of embergen particle simulation

roadblock - embergen particles are not exported with consistent ID's so curves cannot be created

Option 2
use the embergen vdb with .velocities attribute to advect geo-node created points

roadblock - there currently is no way to sample volume information in geometry nodes, there was an experimental build but I can not find where to find the actual build https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/107656

Option 3
somehow use the velocity attribute that does come with embergen alembic particle export and advect the geo-node created points using this 

roadblock - this may be a limitation of my geonodes knowledge, but I am unable to transfer attributes from the embergen particle points to geonode created points


Did you tried to enable experimental volumes option in the settings of the daily build?

Hey @modnop how would I go about doing that? I had a look at the daily build but couldn't find any experimental volumes options
